# Placing a SQLite database into a JSON object to send to a server from iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, sqlite

I am trying to take my entire local sqlite database on an iOS device and send it using http post to my server to insert it into a MySQL database. I am using FMDB for my database and I have 5 tables I want to insert into an object. I was able to do this with my remote server using php but not sure how to do this within xcode. this is my code for sending the object but i dont know how to pack the json object which i stole from another answer ([How do I send the data I have in my sqlite database to the server with HTTP and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288489/how-do-i-send-the-data-i-have-in-my-sqlite-database-to-the-server-with-http-and))

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestdata];

//this kicks off the request asynchronously
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Have you considered sending the SQL equivalent as text instead? As long as you never execute it on the server, it's safe. You'll probably find it smaller, and it's certainly easier to understand.

Comment: No I haven't considered that. I have never worked in iOS or with server side stuff. How would I go about doing that? And what does that achieve over this? I need to take the data in my client side app and insert the rows into the remote server that the remote doesnt contain so I was going to do a loop where it checks that

Comment: Oh. If that's the case, you don't even need the whole dump. Just export the contents of the table you're interested in as a JSON object: An array of dictionaries. Once you get the data into an array of dictionaries, iOS's JSON encoder should be able to take care of this. How are you accessing SQLite? Are you using a wrapper that already converts the records to dictionaries?

Comment: I am using FMDB as a wrapper, I'll have to look into that

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend transferring large BLOB data like that with JSON, but if you absolutely must:

Here, the binary data must be send via a JSON String. To get a "string" from your binary you need to encode your binary data which eventually results in a "string". For example, use `base64` encoding. This encoding will convert your binary data into an ASCII string.

This string can then be used for the JSON string:

JSON:

```
{
    "sqlite_database": "aJ6Fnh1nfh37sg20zBAskfh0QRb ..."
}
```

`NSData` has methods to encode binary data: `base64EncodedDataWithOptions:` and `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`.

You should then be able to send this JSON with a POST request whose content type is `application/json` (don't use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean with that code snippet. what is to the right of the :

Comment: This is just JSON, a *JSON Object* with a key "sqlite_database" and its value, a base64 encoded binary data, as a *JSON String*. From the given information in my answer, it should be straight forward to deduce the corresponding code. You may create a JSON *representation*, that is a NSDictionary with that key and value, then use `NSJSONSerialization` to get a serialized JSON in a NSData object. This data object becomes the body of the POST request.